# How can I give the type inference engine some hints?

Tags: class, haskell, polymorphism, type-inference

In (very) modern GHC's, I can write this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

-- consider this part "library" code, changeable at will
data Container a = Container
data Element
class Foo a where foo :: a -> Int
instance Element ~ a => Foo (Container a) where foo _ = 0

-- consider this part "client" code; bonus points if it can remain exactly as is
main = print (foo Container)
```

Salient points:

1. The client code did not require any additional type signatures.
2. `Container`, which is a polymorphic value (of type `Container a`), was correctly monomorphed to `Container Element`.
3. No newtype wrappers were required in the client code.
4. It is probably not possible to declare another instance of `Foo` whose outermost type constructor is `Container`. This is *not* a property I care about preserving in the following discussion.

Can this be done in a more backwards-compatible way? My first attempt looked like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Container a = Container
data Element
class Foo a where foo :: a -> Int
instance Foo (Container Element) where foo _ = 0

main = print (foo Container)
```

...which gives an error:

```
test.hs:8:15:
    No instance for (Foo (Container a0))
      arising from a use of `foo'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Foo (Container a0))
    In the first argument of `print', namely `(foo Container)'
    In the expression: print (foo Container)
    In an equation for `main': main = print (foo Container)
```

I realized that this error probably arises because the instance doesn't use a type variable as the argument to `Container`, so I also tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Container a = Container
data Element
class Foo a where foo :: a -> Int
instance Convertible a Element => Foo (Container a) where foo _ = 0
class Convertible a b where
    -- convert is not necessary in this tiny example, but it would
    -- be necessary in my not-so-tiny use case
    convert :: Container a -> Container b
instance Convertible a a where
    convert = id

main = print (foo Container)
```

But this just pushes the problem to the `Convertible` type class:

```
test.hs:14:19:
    No instance for (Convertible a0 Element)
      arising from a use of `foo'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Convertible a0 Element)
    In the first argument of `print', namely `(foo Container)'
    In the expression: print (foo Container)
    In an equation for `main': main = print (foo Container)
```

A similar error arises from writing an instance for `Convertible Element Element` instead of `Convertible a a`. My last-ditch attempt was to specialize even further:

```
data Container a = Container
data Element
class Foo a where foo :: a -> Int
instance IsElement a => Foo (Container a) where foo _ = 0
class IsElement a where
    convert :: a -> Element
instance IsElement Element where
    convert = id

main = print (foo Container)
```

...which has the notable benefit of being H98, but the notable downside of still not quite working:

```
test.hs:10:19:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (IsElement a0) arising from a use of `foo'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `print', namely `(foo Container)'
    In the expression: print (foo Container)
    In an equation for `main': main = print (foo Container)
```

So, the question is this: is there some similar implementation that achieves properties 1, 2, and 3 above, yet does not require the type equality operator?

*edit* I thought rank-2 types might help:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes #-}

data Container a = Container
data Element
class Foo a where foo :: a -> Int
instance Foo (forall a. Container a) where foo _ = 0

main = print (foo Container)
```

...but alas, still no dice:

```
test.hs:6:14:
    Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: forall a. Container a
    In the instance declaration for `Foo (forall a. Container a)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  In particular, why do you care that `Container` is polymorphic when you only want the client to work with `Container Element`?

That said, how about using a different kind for the type class?

```
data Container a = Container
data Element

class Foo a where foo :: a x -> Int

instance Foo Container where foo _ = 0
```

Now it truly doesn't matter which type Container is instantiated to.

If this doesn't work, I suspect the answer is "no, you can't do precisely what you want."  Although you could export `container = Container :: Container Element` and have client code use that instead of `Container`.

Edit: given the full context, and that rank-2 types aren't possible either, I am reasonably certain that there isn't a solution given the problem constraints.  The best workaround I can think of is creating a new function `xcast :: XConfig a -> XConfig Layout`.  This would allow you to write `instance Binding (XConfig a -> Foo)`.

Comment: I care that `Container` is polymorphic when I only want the client to work with `Container Element` because that is how xmonad works. =) It has a type `XConfig a` which is a record; one of the fields has type `XConfig Layout -> Foo`. It's easy to write functions of type `XConfig a -> Foo`, and I want my type class to accept these as arguments, monomorph them to `XConfig Layout -> Foo`, and stick them in the field. So the actual class looks something like `class Binding b where bind :: XConfig a -> b -> XConfig a` and `instance Binding (XConfig Layout -> Foo)`.

Comment: Your sentence "no, you can't do precisely what you want" seems to be the right answer, unfortunately. Accepted.